# Create a larger matrix from smaller matrices in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have 3 matrices `A,B,C`. I wish to create a larger matrix of the form

```
D = | 0 A |
    | B C |
```

How to do this in Numpy ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
numpy.bmat([[numpy.zeros(appropriate_shape), A], [B, C]])
```

works, but I'm not sure how to avoid the creation of that big, useless array of zeros. Also, it returns a matrix instead of an array, so make sure to call `asarray` on it if you want an array.