# How to create a large matrix of matrices in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, hdf5, pytables

I am working with a large matrix of size m * n for m,n>100000. Since my data is huge I want to store the matrix in memory and work with HDF5, and PyTables.

However, the elements of my matrix are small matrices of real values of dimension 5*5.

I have already looked at the following post, but I would like to know if there is any other way of storing this type of data in tables?

([Create a larger matrix from smaller matrices in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20345208/create-a-larger-matrix-from-smaller-matrices-in-numpy))

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you actually working with a 100,000*100,000 matrix whose elements are 5*5 matrices?

Comment: why not use pandas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `numpy` there are two relevant structures.

One is a 4dimensional array, e.g. `np.zeros((100,100,5,5),int)`.  The other is an 2 dimensional array of objects.  `np.zeros((100,100),dtype=object)`.  With object array, the elements can be anythings - strings, numbers, lists, your 5x5 arrays, other 7x3 array, `None`, etc).

It is easiest to do math on the 4d array, for example taking the mean across all the 5x5 subarrays, or finding the `[:,:,0,0]` corner of all.

If your subarrays are all 5x5, it can be tricky to create and fill that `object` array.  `np.array(...)` tries to create that 4dim array if possible.

With `h5py` you can chunk the file, and access portions of the larger array.    But you still have to have a workable numpy representation to do anything with them.